# StatusBar Overlays the NavigationBar After Exiting Fullscreen Mode in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am writing an application that Live-streams a video from Youtube using Youtube APIs V3.

However, I faced some problems with the status and navigation bars. 
Before watching the video (entering fullscreen mode) the status and navigation bars are perfectly set (as seen in the following picture) [image]

However, after exiting the fullscreen mode the status bar overlays the navigation bar. 
[image]

The constraints of the navigation bar after exiting the fullscreen mode are as follows: 
[image]

Is there any solution to this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: show the constraints of the navigation bar after exiting fullscreen mode.

Comment: @hardikparmar Thank you for your quick response. I don't have any code specific to the navigation and status bars, they have been added through the interface builder.

Comment: @RaviB Thank you for your quick response. How can I show them?

Comment: try this in your viewDidLoad, 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false'

Comment: use **Debug View Hierarchy** after exiting and click on navigation bar... it will show the appropriate frame of navigationbar in the **Size Inspector**

Comment: @RaviB Thank you. I got the constraints and edited the question to include them

Comment: @manishsharma93 It did not work :(

Comment: Okay try setting your navigation bar frame(Y position) after the status bar height.

Comment: @RaviB thank you very much, but from where can I change these settings?

Comment: When you go into full-screen mode, the top anchor is set to view.topAnchor (ignoring the status bar) and when you exit full-screen mode it should be set to view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor to be placed below the status bar.

Comment: @NathanLevitt Thank you very mcuh. I could not fully understand what you mean, I have tried to reach safeAreaLayoutGuide but I could not :( where should I place the code and what do you mean by view?

Comment: Is that a real navigation bar or a custom view acting as a navigation bar?

Comment: If it is a custom view, can I see the code used to add the navigation bar to the view controller (the constraints)

Comment: @NathanLevitt actually it is a real navigation bar.

Comment: There's no reason to set the height manually like you did for a navigation bar. It looks like you added it in manually instead of wrapping the view controller in a UINavigationContoller. If you added a navigation bar through storyboard, instead of through a UINavationController, you need to set the UIBarPositioningDelegate to set it's position to .topAttached   But I recommend placing your view controller in a UINavigationContoller instead of creating the constraints yourself.